# solution with a recursive function

Tags: algorithm, recursion

Suppose I have:

```
Class Folder{
    int id;
    String name;
    Folder subFolder;
}
```

How can I display folder's hierarchy, assuming that I don't know how many subFolders are there. For example:

1. FolderA contains FolderB (2 levels)
2. FolderA contains FolderB which contains FolderC (3 levels).

I'm looking for an algoritmic solution using a recursive function.
This is my try:

```
function displaySubFolders(Folder f){
    print(f.name);
    if(f.subFolder is NULL) {return 0;}
    else{
        displaySubFolders(f.subFolder);
    }
}
```

Comment: I dunno, maybe if you have a subfolder, you should ask that subfolder to display?

Comment: I need to display Parent FolderA name -> FolderB name -> FolderC name
(Parent Folder name -> Child Folder name -> Grand child Folder name). Not necessarily a three level hierarchy, it could be 5 , 6 or more.

Comment: You never iterate over children of `f`. You should do that to find out all subfolders.

Comment: f has only one child, which has a child on his turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am interpreting your question correctly, it looks like what you have is a linked list where each parent has only one child. In this case, it may be more efficient to avoid recursion entirely (though this would be harder to expand to multiple-descendants later on. Recursion is more extensible for that, I think.)

```
function display_hierarchy(Folder folder) {
    while (folder is not NULL) {
        print folder.name;
        folder = folder.subFolder;
    }
}
```

The primary advantages of this are that no matter how large the linked list is, the amount of memory held for computation remains constant. A recursive strategy, however, consumes more and more stack space as it recurses.

Comment: Unless the question is missing very important details about what a Folder actually contains, this is the correct answer to specific question.  Unless you are going to have an array of subfolders, you don't need to iterate over subfolders and recursion would unnecessarily cluttering your call stack.

Answer (score 3):

A simple recursive solution:

```
public void printHierarchy(Folder f){
    if(f == null) {
        return;
    }
    f.display();
    printHierarchy(f.subFolder);        
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
function displaySubFolders(Folder f, string indent){
    print(indent);
    print(f.name);
    if(f.subFolder is NULL) {return 0;}
    else{
        displaySubFolders(f.subFolder, indent+"    ");
    }
}
```

prints

```
FolderA
    FolderB
        FolderC
    FolderD
```

if `A` contains `B` and `D`, `B` contain `C`

You might replace space with `"--"`, `"**"` or whatever you want.